# Confusion regarding mathematical notations in Greedy and Gumble attack paper

Tags: linear-algebra, probability-theory, machine-learning

The paper Greedy and Gumble attack defines the input space for the text clasifier in the following form, "We assume a model in the form of a conditional distribution, $p_m = (Y|X), X= x \in W^d$ where $W := ${$w_0,w_1,...w_m$}  is a discrete space such as a dictionary of words or space of characters." This is the common way in which input to word based as well as character based CNNs are defined
Now, in case of word based CNNs , I can think of the input to be having $d$ words each along the row, with each word ($w_i$) having an embedding of length $m$. Similarly , in case of character based CNNs, all I can think of is  $d$ characters, each having embedding length $m$ (26?) .

I am just wondering if my assumptions are correct and I would also want to clarify on the meaning of the symbol $:=$ while defining $W$. Does it simply mean that $W$ is a $m$ length vector?

Comment: At least in many probability texts: $:=$ means “defined as” usually for introducing a new object/notation.

Comment: So, in my case , $: = $ defines $W$ as a vector of length $m$ I suppose

Comment: Yup, I'd say so too. Actually, at least in the texts I see this in (Probability with Martingales by D. Williams, for example), they explain the meaning and usage of $:=$ in the introduction, but a paper probably would assume familiarity. If you have any experience in computer programming, it is like the "assignment operator" (though the programming languages I'm familiar with use $=$ for assignment and $==$ for equality).

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. :)